# HasProperty Check on IQueryable<object> - C# .NetCore 2.2

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a method that appends dynamic linq (System.Linq.Dynamic.Core) to an IQueryable:

```
public static IQueryable<object> SearchBySecurityList(List<SecurityListFilter> caSecurityFilterList, IQueryable<object> qry)

public class SecurityListFilter
{
    public string FooOne{ get; set; }
    public string FooTwo { get; set; }
    public string FooThree { get; set; }
    public string FooFour { get; set; }
    public string FooFive { get; set; }
}
```

The method builds a where string at the end of the method by simply binding the where string to the qry:

```
return qry.Where(whereClause, paramList.ToArray());
```

The problem is that some of the objects (passed in as "qry") don't have some of the properties on the SecurityListFilter object. So, lets say I pass in IQueryable<BLAH> qry into my method and the FooFour property doesn't exist. I will get an error stating that the property doesn't exist.

My question is how do I do a property check to see if FooFour exist in IQueryable<BLAH>?

I have tried this but it is always false:

```
if (qry.HasProperty("FooFour") != false)
```

Comment: In any given call to your method, do you expect `qry` to have all objects of the same type? Or could it be called with a mix of different types of objects?

Comment: Every search throughout my app applies this method. So, qry could be for Person on one search or for Place on another search. The method doesn't know what the object being passed into it will be.

Comment: Please include the full method code so we understand your problem better.

Comment: I would but am not allowed. The code in the method will not help solve the problem. I think I found my answer and will post it.

Comment: Does the calling method know which type it's passing in? I'm thinking you could make your method generic, and then look for properties on the generic type. `public static IQueryable<T> SearchBySecurityList<T>(List<SecurityListFilter> caSecurityFilterList, IQueryable<T> qry) { var props = typeof(T).GetProperties();...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better answer but this is currently working for me.
At the beginning of the method I do this:

```
PropertyInfo[] props = qry.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Then, later when I need to check if a property exists:

```
if(!props.HasProperty("SomePropertyOne") || !props.HasProperty("SomePropertyTwo"))
```

EDIT 1:
@StriplingWarrior - Here is my method that is currently working. Sensitive names have been removed and replaced with 'Blah'.

```
public static IQueryable<object> SearchBySecurityList(List<SecurityListFilter> caSecurityFilterList, IQueryable<object> qry, string companySearch, string fpSearch, string poSearch, string controlOwnerSearch, string carSearch)
    {
        string whereClause = "";
        int paramCount = -1;
        int loopCount = 1;
        PropertyInfo[] props = qry.GetType().GetProperties();
        List<string> paramList = new List<string>();
        List<string> finalList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var i in caSecurityFilterList)
        {
            if (loopCount > 1)
            {
                whereClause = whereClause + " || ";
            }

            string innerWhere = "(";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.CompanyName))
            {
                if(!props.HasProperty("Company") || !props.HasProperty("CompanyName"))
                {
                    paramList.Add(i.CompanyName);
                    paramCount++;
                    innerWhere = innerWhere + $"{companySearch} == @{paramCount}";
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.BlahProcessName))
            {
                if (!props.HasProperty("BlahProcess") || !props.HasProperty("BlahProcessName"))
                {
                    paramList.Add(i.BlahProcessName);
                    paramCount++;
                    if (innerWhere.Length > 1) innerWhere = innerWhere + " and ";
                    innerWhere = innerWhere + $"{fpSearch} == @{paramCount}";
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.ProcessOwner))
            {
                if (!props.HasProperty("ProcessOwner"))
                {
                    paramList.Add(i.ProcessOwner);
                    paramCount++;
                    if (innerWhere.Length > 1) innerWhere = innerWhere + " and ";
                    innerWhere = innerWhere + $"{poSearch} == @{paramCount}";
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.ControlOwner))
            {
                if (!props.HasProperty("ControlOwner"))
                {
                    paramList.Add(i.ControlOwner);
                    paramCount++;
                    if (innerWhere.Length > 1) innerWhere = innerWhere + " and ";
                    innerWhere = innerWhere + $"{controlOwnerSearch} == @{paramCount}";
                }
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.CAR))
            {
                if (!props.HasProperty("BLAH"))
                {
                    paramList.Add(i.CAR);
                    paramCount++;
                    if (innerWhere.Length > 1) innerWhere = innerWhere + " and ";
                    innerWhere = innerWhere + $"{carSearch} == @{paramCount}";
                }
            }
            innerWhere = innerWhere + ")";

            whereClause = whereClause + innerWhere;//This should get me something like "() || () || ()"
            loopCount++;
        }

        return qry.Where(whereClause, paramList.ToArray());
    }
```

I then call it like so:

```
IQueryable<MYENTITY> qry = (IQueryable<MYENTITY>)StaticMethod.SearchBySecurityList(
                    input.SecurityFilterList, 
                    GetSearchQueryable(input),
                    "Company.Name",
                    "BLAHProcess.Name",
                    "ProcessOwner",
                    "ControlOwner",
                    "CAR"
                );
```

EDIT 2:
I switched my method to use T instead of object and that works too.

```
public static IQueryable<T> SearchBySecurityList<T>(List<SecurityListFilter> caSecurityFilterList, IQueryable<T> qry, string companySearch, string fpSearch, string poSearch, string controlOwnerSearch, string carSearch)
```

Comment: I can't imagine this working the way you've described. the `qry`'s type is `IQueryable<object>`, so the only properties you would find on it will be those which exist on IQueryables.